# Retrieving Text Instead Of Hyperlink In SharePoint List

Tags: c#, sharepoint, text, hyperlink

I have a

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: Value does not fall
>   within the expected range

I cant change the List View Lookup Threshold, because it is not in a Server environment and I dont have access to it. 
I would need to get the text that is displayed in the list instead of getting the hyperlink (hence the error). 
This is the code I`m using:

```
clientContext.Load(collListItem, items => items.Include(
                   item => item["IT_x0020_Services"]));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
ArrayList itserv = new ArrayList();
foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
{
     itserv.Add(oListItem["IT_x0020_Services"].ToString());
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the `CamlQuery`?

I tried your code just changing `"IT_x0020_Services"` to `"Title"` on a list I have here and it worked properly for me.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://127.0.0.1");
        var oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestList");

        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

        clientContext.Load(
            collListItem,
            items => items.Include(
            item => item["Title"]));

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        ArrayList itserv = new ArrayList();
        foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
        {
            itserv.Add(oListItem["Title"].ToString());
        }
```

Comment: No, I am not missing the CamlQuery, I have that as well. The thing is the column "IT_x0020_Services" returns links, but I only want the text returned that is displayed in the SharePoint List, not the link itself. Thats why I have the error. I think I have to use FieldUrlValue somehow, but I just dont now how exactly.